# getting total from each item in an object

Tags: angular, typescript

How do we map and object and add certain values and then get the total, I wanted to map the object below and then and items from the object. Anyone has an idea ?

**Object:**

```
  [
    {
        "description": "Current Term",
        "monthlyRent": 29971.599999999995,
        "monthsInPeriod": 41.7,
        "rentInPeriod": null
    },
    {
        "description": "Current Term - Rent Adjustment",
        "monthlyRent": 31470.180000000004,
        "monthsInPeriod": 47.96666666666667,
        "rentInPeriod": 1509519.634
    }
]
29971.599999999995 + 41.7   = 30,012
31470.180000000004 + 47.96666666666667 =  31,517
```

**Result:** should be

```
 total = 30,012 + 31,517
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the desired result:

```
const data = [
    {
        "description": "Current Term",
        "monthlyRent": 29971.599999999995,
        "monthsInPeriod": 41.7,
        "rentInPeriod": null
    },
    {
        "description": "Current Term - Rent Adjustment",
        "monthlyRent": 31470.180000000004,
        "monthsInPeriod": 47.96666666666667,
        "rentInPeriod": 1509519.634
    }
];
const total = data
  .map(item => item.monthlyRent * item.monthsInPeriod)
  .reduce((currentValue, acc) => acc + currentValue);
```

I don't actually understand why would you want to add the `monthlyRent` and the `monthsInPeriod` so I multiplied them instead (to get the amount of money that needs to be payed during the number of months). If you want to add them like in your question, just replace the map with `item.monthlyRent + item.monthsInPeriod`.

Comment: Sir last question , how do we round off each value on the object for example monthly rent which is 31470.180000000004 should be  31470 and so on.

Comment: You can use `Math.round()` operator which is available in javascript

Comment: I have another question I have variabla = which is 1000000 and var b which is 125000 when I tried to add it like (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0) ) the result is not added and the output become 100000012500

Comment: It's happening because those are strings. If you convert them to numbers, then you can add them together.

Answer (score 1):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
> Refer the [sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here.
>
> The `reduce()` method executes a user-supplied “reducer” callback
> function on each element of the array, passing in the return value
> from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result of
> running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single
> value. Refer the [sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here.

By combining both you can come up with solution like this:

```
let arry = [
    {
        "description": "Current Term",
        "monthlyRent": 29971.599999999995,
        "monthsInPeriod": 41.7,
        "rentInPeriod": null
    },
    {
        "description": "Current Term - Rent Adjustment",
        "monthlyRent": 31470.180000000004,
        "monthsInPeriod": 47.96666666666667,
        "rentInPeriod": 1509519.634
    }
];

let total = arry 
  .map(obj=> obj.monthlyRent + obj.monthsInPeriod)
  .reduce((value, previousValue) => previousValue + value);
```

Another solution is to use simple for each:

```
 let total2:number=0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.arry.length; i++) {
       let val = this.arry[i].monthlyRent + this.arry[i].monthsInPeriod;
       total2 = total2+val       
    }
```

Please find the attached [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zz6uqs?file=src/app/app.component.ts) here.

Comment: Sir last question , how do we round off each value on the object for example monthly rent which is 31470.180000000004 should be 31470 and so on.

Comment: You can use `Math.round()` operator which is available in javascript. By default number allows taking integers. Appreciate if you can mark it as correct answer if it serves your purpose. Thanks and regards.

Comment: I have another question I have variabla = which is 1000000 and var b which is 125000 when I tried to add it like (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0) )  the result is not added and the output become 100000012500